# Calculating a number using a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I've been trying to calculate a number using a number given by a user in a text box. I've been trying to use the following code. But when I try to test it, nothing happens. Is there something I'm missing? And is there a way that I can make the imprint variable global?

```
     <form>
        <p>How many products do you want
            ingraved?<input id="imprint_amount" name="imprint_amount" type="text"/>
        </p>
        <p>Names to be Imprinted(one per
            line)<TEXTAREA COLS=25 NAME="imprint_text" ROWS=5 WRAP=HARD style="resize:none;"></textarea>
        </p>
         <input onclick="imprint_price" type="button" value="Finish"/>
        <p id="total_cost"></p>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function imprint_price() {
            var imprint_cost,
                imprint_quality,
                imprint_total;
            imprint_cost = 10.99;
            imprint_quantity = document.getElementById('imprint_amount');
            imprint_total = $imprint_cost * parseInt(imprint_quantity, 10);
            document.getElementById('total_cost') = "$" + imprint_total;

        }
```

Thanks, 
Traci

Comment: imprint_quantity should be imprint_text for start...

Comment: Do you get a javascript error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your javascript to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function imprint_price() {
        var imprint_cost,
            imprint_quantity,
            imprint_total;
        imprint_cost = 10.99;
        imprint_quantity = document.getElementById('imprint_amount').value;
        imprint_total = imprint_cost * parseInt(imprint_quantity, 10);
        document.getElementById('total_cost').innerHTML = imprint_total;
    }
</script>
```

Working jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Zt38S/2/

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the `value` property of that [input element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement) you are referencing in your variable:

```
… parseInt(imprint_quantity.value, 10);
```

For arbitrary HTML elements, you need to use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent) (or `innerText` to support old IE):

```
document.getElementById('total_cost').textContent = …;
```

Assigning to an expression as you did should have thrown a quite accurate exception, check your browser's error console for them.

Comment: I don't believe this will work. total_cost is not a textbox but a paragraph. EDIT: nvm, you changed `.value` to `.textContent`

Answer (score 1):

In this line, you'll want to set the `innerHTML` of the element.

```
document.getElementById('total_cost').innerHTML = "$" + imprint_total;
```

This basically sets the text inside the `<p></p>` to be `<p>$x.xx</p>`.

And also this line should be

```
imprint_quantity = document.getElementById('imprint_amount').value;
```

which retrieves the value from the textbox.

Furthermore, when defining the variables, you wrote "quality". It should be

```
imprint_quantity,
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed the quality/quantity typo entirely.

Answer (score 0):

imprint_quantity = document.getElementById('imprint_amount');

=

imprint_quantity = document.getElementById('imprint_amount').value();

Lemme know if that fixes it, a common enough mistake.